# Move Left Floated Element at top while all previous siblings are floated right

Tags: css, css-float

I have following HTML structure. Is there any CSS only way to move Content 3 Div (div3) at the top? I can not change html or sequence of the elements.

I tried using negative margin. which works if i have fixed height of Div 1 and 2. content in div 1 & 2 are dynamic and height can not be fixed.

Please help me to solve this for IE9 and Above.

```css
div.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #eee
}

div.container > div {
  width: 49.5%;
  float: right;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top:5px;
  clear:right;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.container > .div3 {
  float:left;
  clear: none;
  clear:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"> Dynamic <br>Content 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Content <br> 2</div>
  <div class="div3">Content 3</div>
  <div class="div4">Content 4</div>
  <div class="div4">Content 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Based on your comments, I think this should do the trick.  You can use `position:absolute;` on the div3 and `position:relative` on the container div.

```css
div.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  background: #eee;
  position:relative;
}

div.container > div {
  width: 49.5%;
  float: right;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top:5px;
  clear:right;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.container > .div3 {
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"> Dynamic <br>Content 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Content <br> 2</div>
  <div class="div3">Content 3</div>
  <div class="div4">Content 4</div>
  <div class="div4">Content 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, for answer how do i move content 3 to left. I need to have div3 in top left and div1 in right left.

Comment: OK, check if that does what you want ?

Comment: This works as long as content 3 less height then right columns. it would be great to find solution for any height. Accepting answer as it was not part of original question. but would like to see solution without height restriction.